# How do I run expo 50.0.5 iOS simulator on Xcode 13.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, simulator

I have react-native v0.73.2, expo v50.0.5, and Xcode v13.4 installed on my computer.

When I try running it using `npm run ios` or `npx expo start --ios` it will ask me to update my code.

```
Xcode (13.4.0) needs to be updated to at least version 14.1
```

I actually can run the Simulator by executing `open -a Simulator` but it seems the expo can not find the running simulator My macOS is Monterey v12.2.1

[image: npm run ios]

Comment: So...why not upgrade?  SDK 50 release notes recommend [upgrading to XCode 15](https://expo.dev/changelog/2024/01-18-sdk-50#%E2%9E%A1%EF%B8%8F-upgrading-your-app).